# php curl on cronjob not totally silent

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have a php routine that makes a simple cURL call and runs automatically through a cron job. The crontab line for this is:

```
0 * * * * php5 -q /home/curl_call.php >> /home/curl_call.txt
```

This is **curl_call.php**:

```
<?php

    $verbose_log = fopen('log.txt','a');

    $my_curl = curl_init();

    // initialize options array
    $options = array(
         CURLOPT_HEADER => false
        ,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
        ,CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true
        ,CURLOPT_STDERR => $verbose_log
        ,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/json')
        ,CURLOPT_CAINFO => realpath('../../certs/ca.crt')
        ,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 5
        ,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => true
        ,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2
        ,CURLOPT_SSLCERT => realpath('../../certs/client.crt.pem')
        ,CURLOPT_SSLKEY => realpath('../../certs/client.key.pem')
        ,CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE => 'PEM'
        ,CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.mydomainname.com/api.php'
    );

    curl_setopt_array($my_curl, $options);

    // execute cURL and store results (response/error/errno)
    $response = curl_exec($my_curl);
    $error_str = curl_error($my_curl);
    $error_no = curl_errno($my_curl);

    curl_close($my_curl);

    if ($error_no != 0)
        // email error

    fclose($verbose_log);

?>
```

For some reason, each time it runs (always successfully), the server sends me an email with a single line:

```
* Closing connection #0
```

I read in other posts that **CURLOPT_MUTE** has been deprecated, and I can't find other ways to make it "more silent" than it is.

Does anyone knows what this line means?
What can I do to stop it from sending me this single-line email?

Comment: you've got stdout redirected, so the `closing` notice is probably stderr output. try `2>&1` as well, to redirect stderr to stdout, which then gets redirected to your .txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Marc B.

The solution was exactly what you said...

I just had to change my crontab line, adding `2>&1`. It now reads:

```
0 * * * * php5 -q /home/curl_call.php >> /home/curl_call.txt 2>&1
```

This article describes in the detail its meaning:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163352/what-does-dev-null-21-mean-in-this-article-of-crontab-basics

Now the email content ( `* Closing connection #0` ) is being added to the output file (**curl_call.txt**) and the email itself stopped.

Thanks again.